# padding is not working while converting html to doc

Tags: php, html, ms-word, doc

i am using following code to convert html to doc.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header("Pragma: ");// leave blank to avoid IE errors
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'.doc"');
?>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12">
<meta name=Originator content="Microsoft Word 12">
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
 <w:WordDocument>
  <w:View>Print</w:View>
  <w:DoNotHyphenateCaps/>
  <w:PunctuationKerning/>

 </w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding:20px;border:1px solid black;">test data</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In output doc file, div does not have padding and border. But if I use table instead of div, its working. So please suggest me any another way so that I can give padding and border in div. this issue is not because of inline css. Other css are working.

Comment: MS works in mysterious ways. Try assigning a class to the div element and a style the class. Like <div class="padding20"></div> and <style>.padding20{padding:20px;}</style>

Comment: I also tried this, but no result found. @OleHaugset